# AS3 - Flash Vars How to Get Key Name?

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flash-cs5, actionscript-3

I was looking at some adobe documentiation, http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html, but it's just plain wrong. When I do for each over the this.root.loaderInfo.parameters, I can only print out values. I want the actual names of the flash vars, not the values. How can I do this?

```
var paramObj:Object = this.root.loaderInfo.parameters
            for each (var param:String in paramObj)
            {
                trace("key?: " + param);


                //var valueStr:String = String(paramObj[param]);
                //trace("param" + param + " name: " + valueStr);
            }
```

Code above prints out values.

Comment: I think you should use `for (var param:String in paramObj)` insteaf of `for each`.

Comment: it's not wrong at all, you use a 'for each' which is meant to give you the values not the keys. If you use 'for' then you get the keys.

Comment: wow thanks. I never realized there was a difference between for each in and for in

Answer (score 1):

> it's just plain wrong.

I'm not sure what you are talking about, here's the code from the link you provided:

```
// AS3
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
tf.border = true;
addChild(tf);

tf.appendText("params:" + "\n");
try {
var keyStr:String;
var valueStr:String;
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
for (keyStr in paramObj) {
valueStr = String(paramObj[keyStr]);
tf.appendText("\t" + keyStr + ":\t" + valueStr + "\n");
}
} catch (error:Error) {
tf.appendText(error.toString());
}
```

> When I do for each over the this.root.loaderInfo.parameters, I can only print out values.

It's very likely that this is one reason why the example code doesn't use a `for each in` loop but a `for in` loop instead.

---

If you are working with example code, try to stick to it as closely as possible. If you modify the code and it isn't working any more, don't blame the original code.

Comment: Thanks I didn't even realize there was a difference between for each in and for in

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to what i'm using to trace out my flashVars.

```
for (var param:String in paramObj)
{
    trace(param + " : " + paramObj[param]);
}
```